# Can not add Seaborn dependency using Poetry on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, assert, python-poetry

I'm trying to add Seaborn dependency to my module, using Poetry.

I've tried it on different ways, but always without success, maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Here's my current toml config file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "seaborn"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["me"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.9.6"
pandas = "^1.4.1"
jupyter = "^^.0.0"
scipy = "1.7.0"
numpy = "^1.22.3"


[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I've tried on the CLI:

```
poetry add seaborn
```

But no success.
Here's the output

```
 poetry add seaborn
Using version ^0.11.2 for seaborn

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.0s)

  AssertionError

  

  at ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/mixology/incompatibility.py:111 in __str__
      107│         )
      108│ 
      109│     def __str__(self):
      110│         if isinstance(self._cause, DependencyCause):
    → 111│             assert len(self._terms) == 2
      112│ 
      113│             depender = self._terms[0]
      114│             dependee = self._terms[1]
      115│             assert depender.is_positive()
```

If I try to add it to the `toml` config file like `seaborn = "^0.0.1"`
The out put is very similar:

```
poetry update     
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.0s)

  AssertionError

  

  at ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/mixology/incompatibility.py:111 in __str__
      107│         )
      108│ 
      109│     def __str__(self):
      110│         if isinstance(self._cause, DependencyCause):
    → 111│             assert len(self._terms) == 2
      112│ 
      113│             depender = self._terms[0]
      114│             dependee = self._terms[1]
      115│             assert depender.is_positive()
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Interesting. I'm able to reproduce it with the latest stable and latest preview release of Poetry. Can you please open a new ticket in the issue tracker?

Comment: @finswimmer thank you for your reply!
I'm working on this, trying to find a solution and just noticed my module has the same name as the dependency, and i thought "what if this causes an issue!?" Just changed, and I believe it's fixed, but I'm not able to test due to wrong configs now with the venv configs.

Comment: @finswimmer can you try to rename the dependency to "seaborn_", for example and see if it works?

Comment: Ah, good catch. We have already a ticket for raising a better error message here: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1985 and https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5249

Answer (score 4):

After a few hours of dropping modules/restarting Pycharm / Invalidating cache... My project is up-to date without any issue!

For future note:
Do not name your modules/scripts with an already existing package (eg: scipy, seaborn, and so on)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so need to supply a new answer.

This issue has broad applicability beyond just the Seaborn module and should be renamed something like, "Cannot add package using Poetry, AssertionError incompatibility.py:111".

The existing Answer, by @diguex, that I up-voted is exactly the fix needed and this answer helped me with the same problem, attempting to import 'flask-restx' into a demo project named 'flask-restx'.

Long and short, Poetry cannot import a dependency into itself.  Naming the module with an already existing package name will confuse Poetry into thinking it is doing just that.  For more discussion, see: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3491